# MS Access Email Table Hyperlink

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I've created a table that I email based off a query in MS Access and one of the fields is a hyperlink to a file on our server. When the module runs and creates the table in outlook the hyperlink is just the text of where the file is on the server. I'm not that strong in HTML so I'm having a hard time debugging why I can't get that field to create the hyperlink and not just the file location as text. What I've attempted is below to create a hyperlink in the email table for "DRAWING LINK":

```
        "<tr>" & _
"<td bgcolor='#7EA7CC'>&nbsp;<b>Job Number</b></td>" & _
"<td bgcolor='#7EA7CC'>&nbsp;<b>Stock Number</b></td>" & _
"<td bgcolor='#7EA7CC'>&nbsp;<b>Material and Spec</b></td>" & _
"<td bgcolor='#7EA7CC'>&nbsp;<b>Order Size</b></td>" & _
"<td bgcolor='#7EA7CC'>&nbsp;<b>Days In Processing</b></td>" & _
"<td bgcolor='#7EA7CC'>&nbsp;<b>Drawing Link</b></td>" & _
"</tr>"

i = 0

Do While Not rs.EOF

If (i Mod 2 = 0) Then
rowColor = "<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>&nbsp;"
Else
rowColor = "<td bgcolor='#E1DFDF'>&nbsp;"
End If

strMsg = strMsg & "<tr>" & _
rowColor & rs.Fields("Job Number") & "</td>" & _
rowColor & rs.Fields("Commodity Code") & "</td>" & _
rowColor & rs.Fields("Spec") & "</td>" & _
rowColor & rs.Fields("Ord") & "</td>" & _
rowColor & rs.Fields("Idle") & "</td>" & _
rowColor & rs.Fields "<a href="("Drawing Link")" & "</a>""</td>" & _ ***MY HTML WONT CREATE THE HYPERLINK***
"</tr>"
```

Comment: Is the field a Hyperlink type or just Text type with a url string?

Comment: The field is set up as a hyperlink type.

Comment: I don't use Hyperlink type. I prefer Text field then use code to construct hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access Hyperlink field stores hyperlink as a 3-part value separated by # character (review http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html):
`display text#filename#any reference within the file`

Embedding in HTML tag will require extracting middle part. Calculation with intrinsic function HyperlinkPart() can accomplish that. Do extraction in query or VBA.

Correct syntax for string concatenation:

```
rowColor & "<a href='" & HyperlinkPart(rs![Drawing Link], acAddress) & "'>Click Here</a></td>" & _
```

If Hyperlink field has content in Display Text part, can again use HyperlinkPart() function to pull from field and concatenate in place of **Click Here**.

Comment: Your code above does not give me an error and I did turn the hyperlink into text but when the email opens  the drawing link column where the hyperlink is supposed to be is blank. ```rowColor & "<a href='" & HyperlinkPart(rs.Fields("strlink"), acAddress) & "'></a></td>" & _```

Comment: I got the below code to put the address as a hyperlink in the email table so that's a start, based off your help. Yet, it is only as the displaying text, the address is not embedded in the link to take me to the associated file.

Comment: ```"<a href='" & HyperlinkPart(rowColor & rs![Drawing Link], acAddress) & "'></a></td>" & _```

Comment: Certainly won't work with rowColor embedded like that. Need to include some display text or image in the link tag - something visible to click on. See edited answer. Sorry, forgot to include that before. This does work for me.

Comment: It sure wouldn't with the rowcolor. I fat figiner that. Yet your code work for me too! I appreciate all you help.